# Unable to reinstall MySQL

Tags: 14.04, apt, mysql

**What I did before this error:**
*I was trying to install mysql for registration in OpenMRS database and it was succesfully, but i forgot my password. And removed mysql packages, i was getting some errors while this process. Then I tried to install packages and got errors, e.g. "missing dependies", "broken package". I tried to search Google, but nothing helped. So, I can't to remove 'em.*

I can't purge mysql packages, because when I run:

> sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common

I get weird confirmation-output(screen below), it wants to remove plasma-packages, korganizer, etc. So, I can't reinstall MySQL (i forgot password). I'm afraid to confirm this operation, why do it need this packages to delete?

My Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP7Hj.png

Comment: You have physical access to the server? If yes recover the password is quite simple. For the image, it seems that you have not added the -- of command --purge

Comment: Renato Tavares, i tried to use both variants(with/without "--") - the same result. Sorry for dumb question I'm a newbie in this stuff: which server? I've updated description for more info!

Comment: Don't remove mysql-client. Only mysql-server.

Comment: @davidbaumann, **with "--"**:
 the same stuff, wants to delete kde, plasma and others packages. **without "--"**: error: Reading package lists... Done                                                                             
Building dependency tree                                                                                  
Reading state information... Done                                                                         
E: Unable to locate package purge

Comment: ?? Just run `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server`

Comment: @davidbaumann, didn't help. After **Removing mysql-server** starts **Setting up mysql-server-5.5**. And then errors: **start: Job failed to start** **dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5**

Comment: There must be an error message before. Please post to pastebin.

Comment: @davidbaumann, I'm sorry, here it is: http://pastebin.com/tLhng9UN

Comment: What if you just `apt-get install mysql-server`?

Comment: @davidbaumann, I'm getting error: http://pastebin.com/47920kVq

Comment: `apt-get remove --purge mysql-server-5.5` and maybe the last 100 lines of `/var/log/mysql`

Comment: @davidbaumann, for purge: http://pastebin.com/jKc3TteF and for **var/log/mysql** last 100 lines: http://pastebin.com/5z2tLyNq

Comment: Looks like purge worked. `apt get install mysql-server`

Comment: @davidbaumann, the same stuff: http://pastebin.com/ceWaGJfg

Comment: Delete folder `/etc/mysql` and try again.

Comment: @davidbaumann, I deleted **/etc/mysql** then executed **sudo apt-get install mysql-server** and got the same errors, BUT terminal output is less than in previous attempts. Here it's: http://pastebin.com/Ggi6fpcj

Comment: @davidbaumann,i tried to remove another package (not mysql or even similiar to it) AND terminal instead of removing needed package trying to remove mysql-server-5.5. Can this help?

Comment: `dpkg-reconfugure mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: @davidbaumann, **/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server-5.5 is broken or not fully installed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to remove all packages that **apt** was suggesting me, including (muon-updater, qt-propeties and others as you can see on screenshot). I was afraid to do that, because it's very important packages, but all works just fine ;) But not every **purge/remove** command would suggest you to delete a huge amount of packages.

*I used this one:*

> sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common

After uninstallation packages, I was able to install `mysql-server` without any errors.